# SQL query to Manage Visas

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Employees table, Visas table & mobilization table, I need to write a SQL query as a result: EmployeeIdno,Name,Surname,Designation,mobilizationidno,(Most recent Visa Exp Date based on country ) al in one row.

question is: Visa can be multiple and column must be added at the end ( multiple rows coming, I need column in each 1 Employee record )

example I am receiving:

```
'001','john','Doe','Developer','Mob1','Visa1','2018-02-18'
'001','john','Doe','Developer','Mob1','Visa2','2018-02-19'
```

Example I need:

```
'001','john','Doe','Developer','Mob1','Visa1','2018-02-18','Visa2','2018-02-19',Visa3,'2018-02-20'....
```

Visa assigned to person can be increase or decrease

*Employees Table:*

```
IDNO,NAME,SURNAME,DESIGNATION
```

*VISAS table:*

```
IDNO,VISATYPE,IDNO,ISSUEDATE,EXPIREDATE
```

*VISATYPES table:*

```
IDNO,NAME,COUNTRYIDNO
```

*COUNTRIES table:*

```
IDNO,NAME
```

*Mobilization List:*

```
IDNO,EMPLOYEEIDNO,MOBDATE
```

*Mobilization Types:*

```
IDNO,MOBTYPE,COMPANY,LOCATION,EXPECTEDMOBDATE
```

Comment: This is hard to read.  Moving on.

Comment: Show  your query

Comment: OK someone cleaned it up for you.  Question is still not clear.  VTC

Comment: What you are attempting does not make sense in a relational database system.  First Normal Form requires these things: 1) Eliminate repeating groups in individual tables.  2) Create a separate table for each set of related data. 3) Identify each set of related data with a primary key.  The data as you receive it and are attempting to do with afterwards does none of these things.

Comment: if possible do this manipulation at application level. in sql pivot may be a solution